# drupal install module

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, drupal

I have a couple of drupal modules that I would like to install on my Ubuntu LAMP stack. However, I am running into a bit of a problem. I installed drupal using Synaptic, and I cannot find the folder where I am supposed to drop in the unzipped directories. Everything I google says to drop it in `sites/all/modules`, but I cannot find that directory or where I should make it. Where is this directory (`sites/all/modules`)?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

When using Synaptic drupal's default modules and themes are here: `/usr/share/drupal6/sites`. Make the `all/modules` directory and drop in your modules.

As an fyi, to find the files installed using Synaptic or command line, use the following commands:

```
$ sudo updatedb
$ locate drupal6
```

(Change `drupal6` to whatever you are searching for.)